# Relation between Variant Id and other info in Shopify

Tags: shopify

I wanna ask if I could get the other information from variant id in shopify.

Is there any relationship between the variant id and shop id?

How the shopify create the variant id when users create the product or its variant?

Is there any rule?

Or is the variant id related with time?

I think it is related with shopify backend system, but is there anyone know about this?

Answer (score 1):

Shopify is a hosted platform. They have an engineering blog if you are interested in learning about the details of their platform. The bird's eye view to answer your question is that they use a custom MySQL database for entities like shop, products and variants. The ID numbers you see are bigint numbers generated by MySQL. There is zero correlation between these numbers from entities like shop, product and variant. They have nothing to do with time either.